# WebRequest From SQL CLR Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, sqlclr

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to j.v.'s answer I am able to run this but now I am seeing a lot of the following error in rapid succession:

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
(plus about 20-30 more after this)
```

Doing a search for this I see a number of comments that "first chance exceptions" can generally be ignored.  Is this correct in this case?

Also, can someone explain why I am seeing these error messages and if there is a way to resolve?

**OP:**

I have created a WCF REST Service which works correctly when invoked from web browser:

[image]

I am now creating a SQL CLR which is to consume the REST Service.  Here is the code for the SQL CLR:

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    public enum HttpMethods { POST, PUT, GET, DELETE };


    /// <summary>
    /// Test Method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static SqlString ExecFoxPro_SayHello(String name)
    {
        // Put your code here
        return new SqlString ("*** Hello, " + name + "!");
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Return the allowed paths the FoxProConnectWS is configured for
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WebServiceUri"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static SqlString GetAllowedPaths(SqlString serviceUrl)
    {
        String _url = serviceUrl.ToString() + @"/AllowedPaths";

        HttpWebRequest _request = null;
        HttpWebResponse _response = null;

        _request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl.ToString());
        _request.ContentLength = 0;
        _response = (HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse();

        return (SqlString)_response.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am now trying to test the SQL CLR from Visual Studio using the Test.sql file which is setup like this:

```
-- To execute test from within Visual Studio, highlight the row(s) to execute and click hollow green button in this panes header or Ctrl+Shift+E

select dbo.ExecFoxPro_SayHello('Brian')

select dbo.GetAllowedPaths('http://localhost:9876/FoxProConnectService')
```

When I run this in Debug within Visual Studio 2013 I get the followiong error (happens on the `_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl.ToString());` line):

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "GetAllowedPaths": 
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
System.Security.SecurityException: 
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckConnectPermission(Uri uri, Boolean needExecutionContext)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor(Uri uri, ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create(Uri Uri)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   at UserDefinedFunctions.GetAllowedPaths(SqlString serviceUrl)
.
```

What permissions is this expecting and how to I assign?  I would prefer to NOT have to set permissions as this is a program that we distribute to various customers and I cannot guarantee that all customers will have the same permissions setup (i.e., users, access level, etc.)

Comment: For the `ExecFoxPro_SayHello` test method, do not use `String` as a type for the input parameter. Use `Sql*` types whenever they are available, which they are in all but a few cases such as `object` for `SQL_VARIANT` and `DateTime` for `DATETIME2`, and couple of others. Also, do not set `DataAccessKind` to `Read` unless you get an error without it since it adversely affects performance. You also really need to clean up your external resources. One or both of `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` are disposable and need to be disposed of.

Comment: Please see my series of SQLCLR articles for more details: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (FYI: free registration is required for that site).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server management studio, find assembly that hold your clr, go to properties and change permission set either to "External Access" or to "Unrestricted".

Comment: @jv Thank you, that worked.  Just to clarify, I was doing this in Visual Studio 2013 so in order to change the permission set, right-click on the CLR project and select Properties.  Change to the SQLCLR tab and change "Permission level" to "External Access" or "Unrestricted".

Comment: @BrianKE and j.v.: please, please, please do _not_ use `Unrestricted` / `UNSAFE` unless absolutely necessary. For network / file system access you only need `External Access`. And since you are creating this assembly yourself, please do not set the database to `TRUSTWORTHY` just to get the `External Access` part working. You should sign the assembly, create an Asymmetric Key in `master` from the DLL, create a Login from that Asymmetric Key, and then grant that Login the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission.